# UITableView Memory Issue

Tags: swift, caching, memory, tableview, avplayer

[image: memory pressure graph]

I am newbie in swift and I am building an app that similar to vine. First I open my app I am following the codes as you seen in the below

```
    videoArray.removeAll()
    let url = NSURL(string:      "http://....")!
    self.videoArray.removeAll()
    Mellon.getExploreVideos(url,cache: cache, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> () in
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
             self.videoArray = data!
             self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })



override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    cache?.removeAllObjects()
    videoArray.removeAll()
    tableView.reloadData()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self.tableView)
    print("siliniyor")

}
```

In every 8 cell I am calling that getExplore func. I have about 80 videos in my tableview cell in my custom view cell I am building an AVURLAsset and AVplayer. I also set objects for cache in getExplore and when I close view controller I am removing all of them but as you seen from the picture all memory is not removing in every time I scroll tableview begin to end(I have 80 videos that tableView) and I change to view controller and back again I have 20 mb  surplus in memory and at the end my app crush. What should I do for this problem? If the informations are not enough I can edit.

Answer (score 0):

In your viewDidDisappear, make sure you call on to the super.viewDidDisappear as well. To quote the documentation-

> You can override this method to perform additional tasks associated
>   with dismissing or hiding the view. If you override this method, you
>   must call super at some point in your implementation.

This might ease your memory issues. Give it a try.